# Build simple Vertx web server in multi Server

Tags: cluster-computing, vert.x

I'm a newbie in Vert.x and have many issue with it. There is a litle document and tutorial about it
I want to build an web service running in multi server by Vert.x. And if I do that, do I need to config anything, such as DNS...? Anyone has document about Vert.x, please share

Answer (score 0):

This is a very broad and vague question, not really suited to stack exchange. However there are website tutorials available for a number of languages at http://vertxio-hornmicro.rhcloud.com/tutorials.html.

Regarding, DNS etc. I would need to know more about your setup, if you just want to develop something locally try one of the tutorials on the above link.